# How can I track if an Xdebug request is being sent from my browser / docker container?

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a PhpStorm IDE set up with Xdebug, a docker container that is set up with Xdebug included and the browser module applied.  However, when I try to 'pick up the phone' and refresh the code contained in the environment, nothing is ever picked up.

I've tried a variety of ports and server names, along with the tutorials I can find.  I am not certain if it's security or a bad setup with my docker but I am relatively certain the PhpStorm setup is correct.

I've tried exposing ports in the Dockerfile (9000 & 9001)

My .php file is just echo and some math with break points applied:

```
echo("TEST 1<br>");
$test = 2;
echo("TEST " . $test . "<br>");

$testArray = xdebug_get_code_coverage();
var_dump($testArray);
phpinfo();

dd("TEST 3");
```

In my .env file, the following is defined:

```
PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=jumbledowns-demo
XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=localhost remote_port=9001
```

And my Dockerfile sets up Xdebug thus:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug; \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    echo "error_reporting = E_ALL" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "display_startup_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "display_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini;
```

PHPinfo on the browser side shows the code as expected, and the following settings for Xdebug:

```
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9001    9000
```

I've tried using URLs and assigned IP addresses in the above and can change them as needed.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a command line log or output that is showing what Xdebug is trying to call and on what port.

Comment: 1) You do NOT need to expose Xdebug ports -  it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around; RTM. If you "expose" port, Docker will use it instead of IDE. 2) Since it's an outgoing connection, then you must connect to host OS IP, try `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal` 3) use 9001 port for Xdebug (to avoid any possible collisions with php-fpm that also uses 9000 by default) 4) Collect xdebug log and see where it tries to connect (if at all). 5) Check other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug+docker

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise explanation of exposed ports; I was getting to the point of throwing anything at the wall and hoping it would stick.
I thought I had done a reasonable search but the second match from your list was new to me, I'll try and do more tagged searches in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find out what Xdebug is trying to do, you need to set the `xdebug.remote_log` setting to something non-empty, such as `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log`. That file will include all connection attempts, and communication protocol contents if a connection is made.

> remote_host=localhost

Is almost certainly not correct though, as PHP and Xdebug, running in your docker container need to open a connection to this host, and `localhost`, is not going to be the right hostname/IP address. It's more likely that it's `host.docker.internal` or something like that, or rather, hard code the IP address of the machine where your IDE runs, as is accessible to from your docker container.

Comment: Hi there; in trying to add the remote_log, I had to change the method I was using.  Not only did that work perfectly and allow logging to be performed, when combined with the port fixes in the comment above and the correct `host.docker.internal` reference, it all sprung to life and started connecting!  Thank you!